# Wordpress child theme widget customization - Eduma

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, themes, parent-child

I'm in a bit of a struggle at the moment so I could use some help.

The thing is, I need to fix some fields for registration in the Eduma theme
Eduma theme has it's own child theme called Eduma-child, and it's using plugins like Thimpress and Learnpress

As I understand, when you want to make changes, you copy files from the parent theme into the child theme and make customizations in there, but after I **copied** contents of:

> /eduma/inc/widgets/login-popup
>
> /eduma/inc/widgets/login-form
>
> /eduma/inc/widgets/form-login-register.php

into the child theme and made changes, I can't see the changes.

**This is what I did afterwards to confirm what is loaded:**

> 1. I echoed "This is parent theme" in login-popup/base.php in parent theme and "This is child theme" in /login-popup/base.php in Child
>    theme
> 2. Echoed "Parent theme" in form-login-register.php in parent theme and "Child theme" in child theme

**The result:**
I only see "This is parent theme" and "Parent theme"

Can someone please explain how this works as I'm baffled by the Wordpress customisation and I'm in a bit of a hurry.

I looked around, googled and it seems to me that widgets aren't customizable in a way like templates are?